# assign a double pointer to a matrix

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, double

hello i have to assign a matrix to a double pointer i wrote this code for simplify the things.

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{

int ** matrix;
//// initialize the matrix 
matrix = malloc(sizeof(int *)*3);

for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{

    matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*3);

}

// initialize the 2-d array
int matrixx[][3] = { {1,3,4},{5,3,1},{24,5,1} };

for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    ///good kind of assignment 
    matrix[i] = &matrixx[i];
}

/// error how i fix it ?
matrix = &matrixx[0][0];
}
```

Comment: Good for you, and thanks for sharing!

Comment: Oli Charlesworth answered to what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't fix it.  The type of `matrix` is `int **`.  The type of `&matrixx[0][0]` is `int *`.  These are incompatible.

Your "good kind of assignment" is the correct approach if you want to maintain the array-of-pointers mechanism.  However, you have the syntax for it slightly wrong; it should be:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    ///good kind of assignment 
    matrix[i] = matrixx[i];
}
```

Also, you don't need the loop that does this:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
}
```

(You'll incur a memory leak as @Chris points out below as soon as you re-assign these pointers.)  Unless, of course, your intention is to **copy** the contents of the matrix.  In which case, your approach is definitely wrong.

[Note also that you're not calling `free()` anywhere, which means you have a memory leak.]

Comment: i will check you have answered, i have to wait 6 min.

Comment: Well, no, the "good" one leaks memory by doing pointer assignment instead of copying the underlying data (which is almost guaranteed to be what you'll want to do anyway).

Comment: if i do matrix[2][1] = 0; for example i will have an error i can't access to any element.

Comment: @Chris: The problem with the "good" one is not the copying (he's just building up an array of pointers to the first element of each sub-array); the problem is the syntax.  Let me update my answer.

Comment: @Oli - You _can_ do it that way, but the OP's code is currently allocating an array for each `matrix[i]` row, then throwing that allocated memory away by making the pointer point to a row in `matrixx` on the stack. This is definitely a memory leak. The code should either not `malloc` individual rows, or copy data into the `malloc`ed memory rather than doing pointer assignment.

Comment: @Oli ok then you can change the code and let me see who i must allocate each array ?

Comment: My intention is to copy the contents of the matrix.